# CSS + Jquery how to make a div float over other div content

Tags: jquery, css, modernizr

Hi I have the followin div:

```
 <div class="pleaseWait">
            <img src="animation.svg" />
        </div>
```

[image]

I have it just below my `<body>` tag.

My style:

```
.pleaseWait{
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 200px;
    display: none;
}
```

Now, with jQuery depending on ajax calls or whatever I want to display that `<div>` on top of the page centered.

```
$('.pleaseWait').show();
```

Any clue on what css style do I have to add in order to get this result. I want this to be responsive so If I make the browser size smaller the  will move with it.

> By the way Im referencing `modernizr.min.js` in case that works.

Comment: can you show a picture at least?

Comment: In order to use `margin: 0 auto;`, you need to give `,pleaseWait` a width.

Comment: `position: fixed; top: 50%; left: 50%; margin-top: (svg height / -2)px; margin-left: (svg width / -2)px; z-index: 9999;`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the z-index to set the image in front of other elements of your page, like this:

```
.pleaseWait {
margin: 0px auto;
text-align: center;
margin-top: 200px;
display: none;
z-index:2;
}
```

Comment: `2` seems pretty low for getting something to be on top

Comment: Also, "z-index only effects elements that have a position value other than static (the default)" - https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/

Comment: Yes, must be with position: absolute.

Comment: Any position, except for static, will do fine.